# How to make partial match between two strings with mispelled characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of 12 digit alphanumeric codes and I need to match against a list of entries where codes might be misspelled.

For example, if the exact code is "K4I3T9OTG9GZ" the entry I have to check might be "K413T90TGS" (`1` instead of capital `I`, `0` instead of capital `O`, `S` instead of `Z`).

I need to do a partial match to be able to find the right code.

Any ideas?

I already tried `VLOOKUP` with wildcards which worked for most entries with at least five consecutive right characters, but I still have a couple of hundred entries with no match.

Comment: Look for fuzzy match

Comment: consider doing a find/replace for the common errors such as replace K413 with K4I3 etc you must know the common ones...

Comment: Already tried several fuzzy match rules/formula/addons with no luck. Find/replace it's a blindspot cause there are too much combinations, it would take ages...

Comment: These fuzzy match exercises are always a pain!  Check out the AddIn from the link below.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Hopefully that helps you get your stuff done!!

Comment: Already tried also this addon, works great with misspelled real words, but not in my case with random characters in a code :(

Comment: What rule will you use to ensure that the misspelling is acceptable?  In the examples you give, the two strings are different lengths, and, with regard to the shorter length, there are three character substitutions. But maybe some substitutions are OK ( eg `{i,I,1}`, `{0,O}`, and some are not `{x,A,4}`.  And what about the different string lengths?  You'll need to define this before you can really start to come up with a method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help (array formula - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID($B$2,ROW($A$1:$A$12),1),MID($B$1,ROW($A$1:$A$12),1),0)))
```

The formula will check each character, one by one, and compare it against the "original"/"exact" code. In your example the result would be 7, as seven characters are matched exactly:

```
K 4 - 3 T 9 - T G -
{1;1;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;0}
```

Here's the full picture:

[image]

Comment: Not helping me :( This assumes I already have found a list of apparently suitable results and "calculates" the accuracy. I'm a step back, I need to find the results. Since the codes are grabbed from a form, people may have mistaken and mistyped, but I don't know what and where the error is in each case...